# remove double slash in url using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I wanted to remove double slash **ANYWARE** in this url (of course excluding the double slash in http://):
http://localhost:7000/something/something/something/something/something/something/something//

and the only code that I've research and redirects is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0 [R=302,L,NE]
```

but unfortunately, it returns this URL:

http://localhost:7000/C:/xampp/htdocs/something/something/something/something/something/something/something/

Yes it removed the double slash but the URL is wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to work out where the double-slash is coming from?

Comment: @Phil the issue with this is that the user might 'accidentally' add double slash, specifically at the end of the domain which will cause error

Comment: The user might also add `/this/is/not/even/a/real/url`. You can't cater for that sort of thing in `.htaccess`.

Comment: Why you need to remove double slash when user input error url?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path in your rule's destination  :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=302,L,NE]
```